# Multiply Rasters from two subfolders

Tags: python, arcpy, raster, arcgis-10.1, list

I have two subfolders with Rasters named with the same parameters.
I am trying to figure out a way to Loop a multiplication of each raster into a folder with its pair of the other subfolder.
Looks like:.

`SubFolder 1       SubFolder2         Result
178056_WGS.tif     178056_Clean.tif   178056_Mlt.tif
178057_WGS.tif     178057_Clean.tif   178056_Mlt.tif
178058_WGS.tif     178058_Clean.tif   178056_Mlt.tif
178059_WGS.tif     178059_Clean.tif   178056_Mlt.tif`

Another option is to have all Raster in the same folder (workspace) but it is not at all desirable. Do you have any suggestion to do it in Arcgis 10.1 with Python (arcpy)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My final code was based on Aaron's, using Glob.

```
import arcpy, os, glob
from arcpy.sa import *
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

# définir les dossiers et les images à importer
ws1 = glob.glob(r'c:\raster\r1\WGS.tif')
ws2 = "C:\rasetr\ChD\r2"
```

Since r1 and r2 have the same root_name, I just define the workspace for r2 and join the name to get r2.

```
# Dossier de sortie
outws = 'c:\raster\Results'

# Iterateur
for r in ws1:
 basename = os.path.basename(r).split("_Clean")[0]
 r1 = arcpy.sa.Raster(r)
 r2 = arcpy.sa.Raster(os.path.join(ws2, basename + ".tif"))
 result = r1 * r2
 outname = basename + "_Mlt.tif"
 result.save(os.path.join(outws, outname))
```

Comment: Ok, I just modify just answer to my particular conditions. It works. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here is one approach that utilizes the [glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) module:

1. Loop through the rasters in one workspace
2. Within each iteration, extract the basename from each raster
3. Manipulate the basename to match the raster in the second workspace
4. Perform the raster calculation

---

```
import arcpy, os, glob
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

ws1 = glob.glob(r'C:\temp\workspace\*.tif')
ws2 = glob.glob(r'C:\temp\workspace2\*.tif')
outws = r'C:\temp\workspace3'

for r in ws1:
    basename = os.path.basename(r).split("_")[0]
    r1 = arcpy.sa.Raster(r)
    r2 = arcpy.sa.Raster(os.path.join(ws2, basename + "_Clean.tif"))

    result = r1 * r2
    outname = basename + "_Mlt.tif"

    result.save(os.path.join(outws, outname))
```